# Is there a (tiling) WM where there can be several stacked/tabbed windows next to each other on a workspace?

Tags: linux, window-manager, tiling-wm

I'm looking for a Window Manager on Linux that, given a certain window configuration on a given workspace, supports stacking or tabbing of each separate window?
In particular I am thinking of a starting situation with two windows, one on the left and the other one on the right half of the screen. Let's say I then want to open an extra window, that should also be on, say, the right side, and on top of the window that was already present there.
Does anyone know of this possibility without using the mouse to resize and put the window exact in position?
As far as I know, in for instance i3, one has to choose between tiling or tabbing.
I have looked for information online, but I could not find a WM that has this capability (but I might have not used the right search key words).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tab any frame in i3 by pressing the keybinding to tile the window in the direction it is already tiled, then pressing the binding to switch to tabbed mode. After this, any new window opened in this frame is added as a tab, but the other frames still tile around it as they were before.

My default configuration is a two-column split where the left side is firefox tabbed with emacs, and the right half is a two-row split of which each frame contains an rxvt terminal.

Comment: Very cool! However I don't get it to really work yet. Let's start with a Firefox window on the left and a terminal on the right and let's say I want two tabbed terminals on the right. If I understood you well I should press Mod+Shift+'right' when focused on the terminal, then press (by default) Mod+w and then type the key stroke Mod+Enter. I guess I misunderstood you, because I ended up with all three windows in the same tabbed container. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Firefox on the left, terminal on the right. Select terminal, press (I believe) Mod+h for "split horizontal" (the direction it's already split), then press Mod+w for tabbed, then Mod+Enter for a new terminal